# How To Store User Purchases in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

So I'm learning php/mysql and I'm wondering how could I store what item a user purchased in a table.
So far, I made a database called X. X has several tables which are:

(a) Users - This contains username, password and user_id(primary key)

(b) items - This contains item_name, item_price and item_qty

Now I have a problem. Let's say the user buys 5 items. How will I store this in the database? What's the approach to this problem?

Secondly. Let's say 5 users buy the same item, how do I store this in the database and again what is the best approach to this problem?

I'm very new to this so I need help.

Thanks :)

Comment: consider adding two more tables `orders` and `order_items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply have an `Orders` table which links an Item (and quantity) to a User.

```
Orders - 
  user_id (PK, FK -> Users Table)
  item_id (PK, FK -> Items table)
  quantity
  time (PK)
```

---

If you additionally wanted to track transactions you could have another table like this:

```
Transactions -
  transaction_id (PK, FK -> Transaction table)
  user_id (FK -> Users table)
  time
```

And the Orders table would be a little simpler:

```
Orders - 
  transaction_id (PK)
  item_id (PK, FK -> Items Table)
  quantity
```

**Example:**

If 5 users by the same item, in the first method:

```
Orders:

user_id | item_id | quantity | time
1       |  99     |    1     |  31/10/2013 01:01:01
1       |  105    |    2     |  31/10/2013 01:01:01
2       |  99     |    1     |  31/10/2013 01:01:06
3       |  99     |    1     |  31/10/2013 01:03:00
4       |  99     |    1     |  31/10/2013 03:26:09
5       |  99     |    1     |  31/10/2013 04:11:16
```

If 5 users by the same item, in the second method:

```
Orders:

transaction_id | item_id | quantity
       123     |   99    |    1
       123     |   105   |    2
       124     |   99    |    1
       125     |   99    |    1
       126     |   99    |    1
       127     |   99    |    1

Transactions:

transaction_id | user_id | time
       123     |   1     |   31/10/2013 01:01:01
       124     |   2     |   31/10/2013 01:01:06
       125     |   3     |   31/10/2013 01:03:00
       126     |   4     |   31/10/2013 03:26:09
       127     |   5     |   31/10/2013 04:11:16
```

**And finally in answer to your second question:**

Both of these table designs would allow multiple users to purchase the same item without any problems. In the first example the `Orders` table has a compound Primary Key of `PK(user_id, item_id, time_stamp)` which allows for different users to buy the same item, even at the same time.
In the second example the `Orders` table has a compound Primary Key of `PK(transaction_id, item_id)`, and the `Transactions` table has a Primary Key of `PK(transaction_id)` which is always unique (probably generated from a MySQL Sequence).

Comment: What if several users have purchased the same item? Does it have any effect on the table(as in duplicate data for a column)?

Comment: No you have a combined primary key on user_id, item and time. That way even if two users by the same item at exactly the same time, it is still a unique primary key.

Comment: Great example. Thanks, now it's easier to understand it :)

Comment: No problem, feel free to add another comment if you run into any problems.

Comment: One more question, what's the purpose of the foreign key in contrast to the Primary key(which is always unique)?

Comment: The foreign key defines a relationship between two tables. So for example the item_id in the Orders table is a Foreign Key to the Items table. The database would warn you if you tried to enter an item_id which did not exist in the Items table. The Primary Key is how the database determines if the rows are unique or not, also it is indexed so queries on the Primary Key are typically very fast.

Comment: W3Schools has some good resources for understanding foreign keys - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp  Also keep in mind that foreign keys aren't mandatory, they just make things neater. For example if you delete an item from your `Items` table it will warn you if there are any other Tables depending on that item. For example if your `Orders` table had an entry where User 1 bought Item 99, the database wouldn't let you delete Item 99 from the `Items` table.

Comment: Great example you gave there. Looks like I got into advanced SQL without even realizing it. W3schools is great for references.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Obligatory http://www.w3fools.com/ link. Note that you should be using InnoDB to support foreign keys.

Comment: No problem, I think Primary/Foreign Keys are pretty simple once you draw the tables. It is hard to read about them but if you actually grab a pen and paper and draw your schema, they make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Matt InnoDB is the default isn't it?

Comment: @samuel Yes, for MySQL 5.5+ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-default-se.html

Comment: @SamuelO'Malley Check this link. I got a question there concerning fetching information if I want to use PHP.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741722/foreign-key-for-multiple-tables-and-columns

Answer (score 0):

A [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

Probably containing something like:

- user_id
- product_id
- timestamp
- quantity

You might want to replace `user_id` and `timestamp` with another foreign key on an `orders` table.

Answer (score 0):

you need an another table that make relationship between these table (Users,items). I called it an `order_tbl` that store `users_id,items_id,item_quantity,time_stamp`. Time_stamp is used for time value (you doesn't need this now, but it help you near future).

Answer (score 0):

One method (w/o adding more tables) is to add a foreign key to the **items** table for the **user_id** of the purchaser. Note, set this field as an index.

Here's some examples:
User 101  buys item A, quantity 1
User 101  buys item B, quanty 2
User 102  buys item A, quantity 5

Items Table
item_name item_price item_qty user_id
A  $1 1 101
B  $2 2 101
A  $1 5 102

Another (my preference) is to create a third table for **purchases** and use the **items** table only for listing unique instances of items, and add a primary key (**item_id**) to the **items** table.

**Items**
item_id (primary key) 
item_name

**Purchases**
purchase_id (primary key)
item_id (foreign key)
item_qty
item_price
date_of_purchase

Comment: Your first solution would result in a lot of redundant data. The item_name and price would be repeated for every purchase.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to have 4 tables

> ```
> TABLE `user` (
>   `id`,
>   `username`,
>   `password`,
>   ...
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
>
> TABLE `product` (
>   `id`,
>   `name`,
>   `price`,
>   ...
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`));   
>
> TABLE `order` (
>   `id`,
>   `user_id`,
>   `time`,
>   ...
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>   FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user`(`id`));   
>
> TABLE `order_product` (
>   `order_id`,
>   `product_id`,
>   `quantity`,
>   ...
>   PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`,`product_id`),
>   FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`),
>   FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `order` (`id`));
> ```

The `order_product` is a junction table to establish a many-to-many relationship between the `order` and `product` table.

That's it.

Comment: I noticed that in table "user", you used a column called "id" and in table order you used user_id, wouldn't that create some sort of conflict when trying to harvest the data? And also I noticed the primary key(id) in several tables, won't that affect the tables, since it will be creating new ids every time, thus making the information irrelevant?