# How to use foreign keys with PHP

Tags: mysql, database, normalization, denormalization

So I understand how to create foreign keys and I know what is the purpose of the FK. But I have a problem in understanding How to use them. I asked a question regarding Foreign keys [HERE(Click link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741722/foreign-key-for-multiple-tables-and-columns)

Here is what I made:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE items(
  i_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
  price DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (i_id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_purchase(
  i_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  name TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
  id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (i_id) REFERENCES items(i_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES items(name),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES user(id)
);
```

Now my question is how do I make the most out of this using PHP? From the link above, people have suggested that it's good to use only one foreign key in the user_purchase table, but what if I want several columns? Why don't we use several foreign keys for different columns of the same table?

I am using mysql and php. I would appreciate it if you could show some examples of how you use PHP with the tables which have foreign keys to get get information using MYSQL commands. I really need a thorough explanation.

I also need to understand the terms Normalization and Denormalization. I would appreciate if you could give some links which explain these terms in great detail with examples or if you have any suggestion for some great books for beginners in database design, implementation, etc, I would really appreciate.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The concept of foreign keys is independent of programming language. Also there is no need to create a key on items(name)

Comment: I know it is independent of the programming language, but as you say, I don't need to create a key on items(name). Let's say I want to fetch the i_id, id and name and display them on my page using PHP, would I need the foreign key then or it doesn't matter?

Comment: _"Why don't we use several foreign keys for different columns of the same table?"_: Why should we? How is that justified?

Answer (score 26):

### Foreign key columns/constraints disambiguation

> So I understand how to create foreign keys and I know what is the
>   purpose of the FK. But I have a problem in understanding How to use
>   them.

Assuming you are referring to **the foreign key constraints**, the short answer would be *you just don't use them*.

And here comes the long one:

We are accustomed to refer to *columns being foreign keys* to other tables. Especially during the normalization process, phrases like *"`user_purchase.i_id` is a foreign key to the `items` table"* would be very common. While that's a perfectly valid way to describe the relationship, it can get a little fuzzy when we reach the implementation phase.

Suppose you have created your tables *without* the `FOREIGN KEY` clauses:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE items(
  i_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
  price DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (i_id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_purchase(
  i_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  name TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
  id INT(11) NOT NULL,
);
```

Notice that, relation-wise, the foreign key *columns* are *still implemented*. There's a column that references the `user` table (`id`) and another one that references the `items` table (`i_id`) -- let's put the `name` column aside for a moment. Consider the following data:

```
  user              user_purchase    items
| id  username |    | id  i_id |    | i_id  name            price |
| 23  john     |    | 55   10  |    |  10   chocolate bar    3.42 |
| 55  mary     |    | 70   10  |    |  33   mobile phone    82.11 |
| 70  fred     |    | 70   33  |    |  54   toothpaste       8.67 |
                    | 55   10  |    |  26   toy car          6.00 |
                    | 70   26  |
```

The relation is there. It is implemented by means of the `user_purchase` table, which holds information as to *who bought what*. If we were to query the database for a relevant report, we would do:

```
select * from user_purchase p
join user u on (p.id=u.id)
join items i on (p.i_id=i.i_id)
```

And that's how we use the relation and the foreign key *columns* involved.

Now, what if we do:

```
insert into user_purchase (id,i_id) values (23,99)
```

Apparently, this is an invalid entry. Although there is a user with `id=23`, there's no item with `i_id=99`. The RDBMS would allow that to happen, because *it doesn't know any better*. Yet.

That's where foreign key *constraints* come into play. By specifying `FOREIGN KEY (i_id) REFERENCES items(i_id)` in the `user_purchase` table definition, we essentially give the RDBMS a rule to follow: *entries with `i_id` values that are not contained in the `items.i_id` column are not acceptable*. In other words, **while a foreign key *column* implements the *reference*, a foreign key *constraint* enforces the *referential integrity***.

Note, however, that the above `select` wouldn't change, just because you defined a FK constraint. Thus, *you* don't use FK constraints, the RDBMS does, in order to protect your data.

### Redundancies

> ...what if I want several columns? Why don't we use several foreign
>   keys for different columns of the same table?

Ask yourself: Why would you want that? If the two foreign keys are to serve the same purpose, the redundancy will eventually get you in trouble. Consider the following data:

```
 user_purchase                   items
| id  i_id  name           |    | i_id  name            price |
| 55   10   chocolate bar  |    |  10   chocolate bar    3.42 |
| 70   10   chocolate bar  |    |  33   mobile phone    82.11 |
| 70   33   mobile phone   |    |  54   toothpaste       8.67 |
| 55   10   toothpaste     |    |  26   toy car          6.00 |
| 70   26   toy car        |
```

What's wrong with this picture? Did user `55` buy two chocolate bars, or a chocolate bar and a toothpaste? This kind of ambiguity can lead to a lot of effort to keep data in-sync, which would be unnecessary if we just kept one of the foreign keys. In fact, why not drop the `name` column altogether, since it is implied by the relation.

Of course, we could resolve this by implementing a composite foreign key, by setting `PRIMARY KEY(i_id,name)` for the `items` table (or defining an extra `UNIQUE(i_id,name)` index, it doesn't realy matter) and then setting a `FOREIGN KEY(i_id,name) REFERENCES items(i_id,name)`. This way, only (i_id,name) couples that exist in the `items` table would be valid for `user_purchases`. Apart from the fact that *you would still have **one** foreign key*, this approach is totally unnecessary, provided that the `i_id` column is already enough to identify an item (can't say the same for the `name` column...).

However, there's no rule against using multiple foreign keys to a table. In fact, there are circumstances that demand such an approach. Consider a `person(id,name)` table and a `parent(person,father,mother)` one, with the following data:

```
 person             parent
| id  name    |    | person  father  mother |
| 14  John    |    |   21      14      59   |
| 43  Jane    |    |   14      76      43   |
| 21  Mike    |
| 76  Frank   |
| 59  Mary    |
```

Obviously, all three columns of the `parent` table are foreign keys to `person`. *Not for the same relation*, though, but for *three different ones*: Since a person's parents are persons too, the two corresponding columns must reference the same table `person` does. Note, however, that the three fields not only *can* but also *have to* refer different `person`s in the same `parent` row, since noone is his own parent and noone's father is his mother as well.

Comment: Great explanation. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Foreign keys are used in joins. For instance, if you want to know the usernames that purchased a particular item, you would write:

```
select u.username
from items i
join user_purchase up on i.i_id = up.i_id
join user u on u.id = up.id
where i.name = "Some product name"
```

They may also be used by the database engine itself. It can detect if you create a row in `user_purchase` whose `id` or `i_id` column doesn't match anything in the referenced column in the other table.

You should **not** replicate the `name` column in the `user_purchase` table. The `name` is just an attribute of the `item`, it's not specific to any particular purchase. If you need to get the name of the item that was purchased, join with the `items` table.

Comment: Foreign keys are _not_ used in joins, you may very well have the one without the other. The second paragraph, however, describes the real (and sole!) purpose of FKs and IMHO should be emphasized as much as possible.

Comment: @geomagas Well, they describe the relationship between tables, and you wouldn't have tables with relationships if you didn't need to join them. This is the only sense I could make of the question of how you "use" a FK.

Comment: True. And I, myself, can understand the meaning of your words. But still, a join doesn't _use_ FKs per say, merely _columns that may or may not have FKs applied to them_. It's only natural to create FKs on related data, but sadly not everyone takes care of that. OTOH, the only thing that _really uses_ FKs is the RDBMS, the way you describe it later. FKs are really _constraints_, and I think that's how they should be defined, described and used.

Comment: @barmar If I try to enter a value that does not exist what's going to be returned? Notice? Warning?

Comment: @fat_mike It will return 0 rows if you enter a name that doesn't exist.

Comment: @barmar No, I mean if you insert a value that not exists in the other table and you have set it as a foreign key what kind of error will be returned.

Comment: **ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading so many links, just try to implement this in any simple project. I'm just explaining how we gonna use the above tables.

Suppose you 3 users in `user` table and 5 items in `items` table.

`user` table

```
id  |  username |  password 
 1      abc         123
 2      def         456
 3      qwe         987
```

`items` table

```
i_id  |  name   |  price 
 1      item 1    6
 2      item 2    8
 3      item 3    11 
 4      item 4    3
 5      item 5    14
```

your `user_purchase` table look like this

CREATE TABLE user_purchase(
  i_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (i_id) REFERENCES items(i_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES user(id)
);

There is no need of item name again in this table. So I have removed.

```
i_id |  id  
 1      1      
 1      2
 2      2      
 3      3
```

In the above table we will get, user 1 has purchased item 1, user 2 has purchased item 1,item 2 and user 3 has purchased item 3.

This is how normalization works. You can use MySQL JOIN for getting user name and item details

```
SELECT B.user_name,C.name AS item_name,C.price
FROM user_purchase A 
JOIN user B ON A.id = B.id
JOIN items C ON A.i_id = C.i_id
```

Here is foreign key use to join

```
A.id = B.id
A.i_id = C.i_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You treet tables with foreign keys in php the same way, as if they had no foreign keys. Foreign keys are defined in the database and have (almost) nothing to do with php. The only thing you have to do in php is reacting to potential errors that can be returned by sql queries, which brake the foreign key constraint (typically DELETE queries).

And for your database schema, you should drop column "name" from "table user_purchase". It is redundat.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the normalization/de-normalization point:

Normalization is a process of trying to remove redundancy in your database - in your example the `name` field in `user_purchase` is redundant - I can find out the name of the item by looking it up in the `items` table using `i_id`.

So if we were to look at normalizing `user_purchase` we'd probably remove the `name` field and use a `JOIN` to retrieve that when we needed it. This would, of course, also mean we don't need the second `FOREIGN KEY` reference to `items`.

De-normalization is basically going the opposite way - adding redundancy - usually done for performance reasons.

However, in your example you might also consider de-normalization for business reasons too. For example you might decide it is important to store the product name as it was when the user actually purchased it (rather than what it's called now) - just in case you need to be able to re-print an invoice for example. However even in this case you wouldn't want the `FOREIGN KEY` back to `items` (as it would "break" if the product was re-named).

Comment: The last paragraph has nothing to do with denormalization. The result would still be normalized, as there would be no redundancy. Also, the `price` field would provide a more real-life example for this.

Comment: @geomagas: You're right of course. I did think later that my example was a bit forced!